# "Due to my past this remark was far more insulting than [...] for other people" v. "Because I was abused as a child I have lower levels of restraint"

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales

1. Can someone please simplify and teach how to distinguish arguments 1 v. 2 at the bottom? They deal with s 54(3) below.
2. They look the same to me because both arguments adduce D's past abuse as a child, to legitimize why ‘a useless whore’ made her kill.
3. In other words, doesn't argument 1's "this remark was far more insulting than it might be for other
   people" in argument 1 = argument 2's "I have lower levels of restraint than other people"?

[*Concentrate Criminal Law* (2020 7 edn)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Criminal-Law-Concentrate-Revision-Study-dp-0198854986/dp/0198854986/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p 87

> ### Loss of control

> This partial defence replaced that of provocation. [Section 54](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2009/25/section/54) of the [Coroners and Justice Act] 2009, provides:

> > (1) Where a person (‘D’) kills or is a party to the killing of another (‘V’), D is not to be convicted of
> > murder [but of manslaughter] if—
> > a) D’s acts and omissions in doing or being a party to the killing resulted from D’s loss of
> > self-control,
> > b) the loss of self-control had a qualifying trigger, and
> > c) a person of D’s sex and age, with a normal degree of tolerance and self-restraint and in the
> > circumstances of D, might have reacted in the same or in a similar way to D.
> > (2) For the purposes of subsection (1)(a), it does not matter whether or not the loss of control
> > was sudden.
> > (3) In subsection (1)(c) the reference to ‘the circumstances of D’ is a reference to all of D’s circumstances
> > other than those whose only relevance to D’s conduct is that they bear on D’s
> > general capacity for tolerance or self-restraint.

p 89.

> ### The objective test

> Even if the jury is persuaded that D lost their self-control as a result of a qualifying trigger,
> it must still be persuaded that an ordinary person of D’s age and sex, with a normal degree
> of tolerance and self-restraint, would have killed as the defendant did. The jury can take
> into account the ‘circumstances’ D was in. So it can take into account that D was, for example,
> the victim of domestic abuse or their mental health condition, in deciding how serious
> the qualifying trigger was and how they might be expected to respond (*Rejmanski* [2017]).
> However, it seems that the circumstances cannot affect the degree of tolerance and self-restraint
> expected. The voluntary consumption of alcohol is not a factor that can be taken
> into account, *Asmelash* [2013].
>       Note the jury should consider whether or not the ordinary person would have acted
> as the defendant did. This means the jury can consider the method of killing used. In

p 90.

> *Goodwin* [2018] the court accepted that an ordinary person in the defendant’s position might
> have killed the victim, but would not have subjected the victim to a five-minute assault of
> repeated beatings.

> Consider this example: D has been abused as a child and V describes her as ‘a useless whore’. The
> law allows D to argue: **[Argument 1.]** ‘Due to my past this remark was far more insulting than it might be for other
> people and so it was understandable I responded by killing.’ But D cannot say **[Argument 2.]** ‘Because I was abused
> as a child I have lower levels of restraint than other people.’
>        Also, do you agree that age and sex should be taken into consideration when assessing loss of
> self-control? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments 1 and 2 are not equivalent.

Argument 1 is premised on a particular *qualifying trigger* that happens in the moment (namely, the insulting remark) whereas argument 2 is premised on the *general capacity for self-restraint* that only D --unlike the average person-- possesses. *Qualifying trigger* means a condition that develops shortly (even if not immediately) before the crime, which ought not to be confused with the criminal's [habitual] *propensity* to commit a crime.

Section 54(1)(b) allows a qualifying trigger to result in leniency, and 54(3) rules out D's personal attributes/history as a factor for leniency. More precisely, 54(3) constrains the meaning of 54(1)(c).